# CreateEnclave() function Windows

Tags: windows, enclave

I am using `gcc` and compiling my programs. I have decided to enclaveapi and tried to use `CreateEnclave()`. It says `<enclaveapi.h>` does not exist when I add the header.

When I use the header `<winbase.h>` it returns `undefined reference to 'CreateEnclave'`. How do I get rid of this error? I am using basic compilation with `gcc main.c -o main.exe -mwindows`.

Comment: By `gcc` do you mean MinGW?

Comment: yes sir @kichik

Comment: They might not support it yet. If updating MinGW doesn't help, you can always manually call functions using `GetProcAddress()`.

Comment: Do you know if there is a place that I can download `enclaveapi.h`? @kichik

Answer (score 0):

`<enclaveapi.h>` is in the latest Windows SDK.  [Download here](https://developer.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/downloads/windows-10-sdk). The SDK provides among other things, the latest headers and libs for building windows code.  update your compiler switches to use the new paths.

Alternatively, you can probably just dynamically load the API without having to install the new SDK:

```
typedef PVOID (__stdcall *create_enclave_type)(HANDLE,LPVOID,SIZE_T,SIZE_T,DWORD,LPCVOID,DWORD,LPDWORD);
create_enclave_type fnCreateEnclave;
HMODULE hKernel = LoadLibrary(L"kernel32.dll");
fnCreateEnclave = (create_enclave_type)GetProcAddress(hKernel, L"CreateEnclave");
```